# Why won't this regexp in htaccess work properly?

Tags: .htaccess

I currently use the following htaccess code to remove all php extensions and also allow the /index.php page to load without the word "index" seeing that's the cost of removing .php:

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1.php [L]
```

I used to create a new page for every single user but as one could probably see, this is not such a good idea. So i deleted all the user pages and i would include them a different way but i would need to pass the requested page as a get parameter to another file. So I decided to route every main level (/) requested page through a file in a different directory, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ some/page.php?requested_page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

But it does not work with the /index.php page if someone just requested it like this: /

i changed the code to:

```
RewriteRule ^(<?!)([^/]+)$ some/page.php?requested_page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

and now the "/" request works and any page that really exist works, but the "fake user pages" now dont work. is there way i can possibly do both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the regex to use `*` instead of `+`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ some/page.php?requested_page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Because the `/` request is an empty URI (the leading slash is stripped before the rules get applied).